# Genus of a number field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, number-fields

I'm reading *Algebraic Number Theory* by Neukirch. In chapter 3, he defines the genus of a number field as
$$ g = \log  \frac{  |\mu (K)| \sqrt{|d_K|}}{2^{r} (2\pi)^{s}}  $$ where $|\mu(K)|$ is its cardinality.

I would like know the motivation behind this definition and if there is any relationship with the actual genus of the associated scheme $X = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_K)$. I was searching up online and found very little about it.

Comment: Is the formula for $g$ that you've written (more or less) equal to $$-\log\operatorname{Residue}_{s=1} \zeta_K(s)\;?$$ If so, this suggests that if you replace $K$ with the function field of a curve $C$, then the corresponding residue formula would give the genus of $C$.  (Although if working with $C/\mathbb F_q$, I'd expect you'd want to take $\log_q$.)

Comment: It doesn't look like the log residue of zeta - the class number and regulator are missing! This definition seems weird and useless to me.

Comment: Even though the class number and regulator are absent, the rest of the stuff leaps out at me as appearing in the residue of $\zeta_K$ at $1$...

Comment: @Satan'sMinion Good point, so it's the log residue of zeta for an imaginary quadratic field of class number 1!

Comment: I think Neukirch's explanation is quite clear, this is exactly the notion of genus which ensures that the analogue of Riemann-Roch holds. The relation with the class number formula is since Riemann-Roch is essentially equivalent with Poisson summation on the additive group of adeles and via Tate's proof of the class number formula using Poisson summation.

Comment: @JoeSilverman The residue of $\zeta$ at $s=1$ for function fields is not correlated with the genus - I believe it is known to have a limiting distribution as the genus goes to infinity.  Rather it gives the discrepancy between the log base $q$ of the discriminant (which gives the genus exactly) and the log base $q$ of the class number (which gives the genus approximately).

Comment: So taking the log of the discriminant makes sense for a number field notion of genus, and then one can take local factors at $\infty$ to replace the local contribution to the discriminant at $\infty$ that exists in function fields. I'm not sure why the units are there, maybe because the discriminant of a function field of degree $n$ over $\mathbb F_q(t)$ is $q^{ 2g + 2n-2}$ and one can mimic the $q^{-2}$ factor with $(q-1)^{-2}$ which is the order of the unit group raised to the power $-2$.